# Height Loss In Descend with increase in altitude

Tags: pilots, student-pilot

Will the physical height lost in 3D would be same if I descend with 500 fpm from 2000 to 1000 feet compared to descend with 500fpm from 20000 to 19000

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Based on your current phrasing, the height difference here is -1000ft, the rate of descent is completely unrelated -- but that's just simple arithmetic, and not an aviation question.

Answer (score 1):

No, the exact physical height loss will not be the same when comparing different altitudes because aircraft altitude is based on pressure altitudes and altimeter settings.

When you add local temperature and pressure differences into the equation, the altitudes will never be exactly 1,000 feet apart. That is one of the reasons why Air Traffic Control uses 2,000 foot separation above 29,000'.